# Reference Request: Soft handed text on duality theory?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Can anyone recommend a text on duality theory which includes basic formulation of the primal and dual formulation and some introduction to minimax problems? Preferably having some computation in finite dimensional vector spaces with plenty of examples.

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many (but of course closely related!) notions of "duality". By far the most powerful is the [Fenchel-Rockafellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem). This this 'technology', you can convert rather complicated problems into dual form in just one line of calculation. It some cases, the problem so-obtained is much easier to attack than the original. To get the ball rolling, start with [this](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf) one-page material by Bauschke. For a more advanced exposition, see [Nesterov](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.449.189&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or [Bauschke](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Optimization/MRFpapers/nesterov05.pdf).

Comment: Those are some interesting choices, but both assume a rather specific problem structure, and may not be well suited for a more general study of duality.

Comment: The user did not ask for a "general study of duality". These choices are utterly sufficient for what the user demands.

Comment: No worries, we can agree to disagree, except perhaps Nesterov is never "soft handed"! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Boyd and Vandenberghe is a good place to start. It makes the discussion of duality about as simple as possible, and it certainly has many good examples. The book is free online.